# Fix relative path issue: ENOENT: no such file or directory?

Tags: node.js, file, express

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

```
var article = fs.readFileSync('../views/articles/'+slug+'.hbs', 'utf8');
```

This worked on dev server but not on production? Why would that be? How do I figure out what path the script is actually trying to read? the file is definitely there.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the file?

Comment: It says -rw-rw-rw-  not really sure what that means, what permissions does it need?

Comment: Permissions are unrelated to ENOENT.

Comment: ENOENT means there is no entry for the file - i.e. it doesn't exist at the resolved path

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, and I just tried console.log('path exist?',fs.existsSync('../views/articles/'+slug+'.hbs')); and I got false, so it must just be because of the path. But how do I see what directory it's actually looking at because it seems like it should be right.

Comment: Did you check what value `slug` actually has?

Comment: to find the path its actually looking at, you could try logging `require('path').resolve('../views/articles/'+slug+'.hbs')`

Comment: Or print `fs.realpathSync('../views/articles/'+slug+'.hbs')`.

Comment: Thanks, seems I didn't need the '../' at the beginning, I don't really get why though.

Comment: so it seems my dev environment is by default starting at /project/bin where my production server doesn't use that bin folder and is just at the /project root. Is there a way to redirect this without completely rearranging my dev environment?